# Limits of oscillating functions by L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits

Am I right that the limit of any oscillating functions cannot be evaluated by L'Hopital's rule?I mean if there are any oscillating term in the numerator or denominator of the f(x)/g(x) we cannot evaluate the limit by l'hopital's rule.Is it true?There is 0/0 and inf./inf. form.

Comment: What do you mean by oscillating functions?

Comment: Like sin(1/x) oscillates as x tends to 0 and sinx,cosx oscillate as x tends to infinity.

Comment: You apply L'Hospital's rule to $f/g$ only when $f/g$ is in $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ form

Comment: Suppose the function is $\sin(x) / \tan(x)$ at $x=0$, then you can apply L' Hospital's rule.

Comment: Can we not apply l'hopital's rule when f(x) or g(x) oscillate at that value of x where we are finding limit?Here f(x) is the numerator and g(x) is the denominator of the function that forms 0/0 or infinity/infinity form.

Comment: @HunardeepBrar, can you give an example of the kind of limit you have in mind in your question?

Comment: Limit of (5x^2-3sinx)/(x^2+10) as x tends to infinity.And lim(x+sinx)/x as x tends to infinity.

Comment: Note that as PNDas wrote in his answer, one of the conditions for l'Hopital's rule is that the limit of $\frac{f'}{g'}$ exists. For your first limit, you can apply l'Hopital's rule once. If you apply it a second time, you're going to get a limit that does not exist, whereas the initial limit does exist. For the second limit, you can't even apply l'Hopital's rule once because then you immediately get $1+cosx$ whose limit does not exist, whereas we know the initial limit exists. When the limit of $\frac{f'}{g'}$ does not exist, l'Hopital's rule doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Or a better way to say it might be... if you apply l'Hopital's rule and get a limit that does not exist, then you get no information about the initial limit.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have to find limit of $\frac f g$ at c  and we have some conditions

1. $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ or $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \pm \infty = \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$
2. Both $f,g$ are differentiable function except(possibly) at $x = c$ and $g'(x) \neq0$ except(possibly) at $x = c$.
3. $\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f'}{g'} $ exists ,

then only we can apply L Hospital's rule which guarantees that
$$\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f}{g}=\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f'}{g'}.$$
You see L Hospital's rule requires a strong hypothesis.
However if I take $f(x)=x^3 \sin{\left(\frac 1 x\right)}, g(x)=\tan(x)$ then see it satisfies all the condition (check!).

Therefore, by L Hospital's rule,
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f}{g}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'}{g'}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3x^2\sin{\left(\frac 1 x\right)}-x\cos{\left(\frac 1 x\right)}}{\sec^2(x)}=0.$$
But if $f$ were $\sin{\left(\frac 1 x\right)}$, then we won't be able to apply L Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

No condition about oscillating functions are contained in the statement of the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof), therefore l'Hospital rule can be applied also for these cases, as for example

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log x}{x \sin x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac1x}{ \sin x+x \cos x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{ x\sin x+x^2 \cos x} $$

which doesn't exists therefore we can't conclude nothing but

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin x\log x}{x^2 } = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\cos x \log x + \frac{\sin x}{x}}{ 2x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x\cos x \log x+\sin x}{2x^2} =0 $$